# How to reference "anchor links" differently from regular Links in CSS

Tags: html, css

How to differentiate "anchor links" from regular Links in CSS?!

Is there anything like pseudo-elements or checks IF the Link is an Anchor Link?!

I need to style them, put them in different colors.

It is an existing and old website where I am updating several things, and those Anchor Links were put there 8 years ago and many, it is too late to put them around a special class name;

It is a general question, Anchor Links as Anchor Links, they can not be referenced ather way & they are mixed with Regular Links on a 5 000 pages...

Although this seems a simple thing I could not find anything related on google....

As for code example

```css
a {color:red;text-decoration:none;}

a::Anchor {??? Can I or Can't I}
```

```html
<article>
<a name="Mark1">Anchor Link 1</a>

<a href="http://google.xyz"> Reg Link 1</a>

<a name="Mark2">Anchor Link 2</a>

<a href="http://google.xyz"> Reg Link 2</a>

<a name="Mark3">Anchor Link 3</a>

<a href="http://google.xyz"> Reg Link 3</a>

<a name="Mark4">Anchor Link 4</a>

<a href="http://google.xyz"> Reg Link 4</a>

<a name="Mark5">Anchor Link 5</a>

<a href="http://google.xyz"> Reg Link 5</a>

</article>
```

Comment: The `name ` attribute was deprecated ages ago and shouldn't be used. And why would you have an anchor without an `href`?

Comment: If I remember right, the HREF tag was removed from Anchors, because the page was jumping incorrectly and I read an advice to remove them;

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the selection by using attributes :
if the link contains name property, it's an anchor link, and if it contains href property, it's an external link.
example :

```css
a[href] {
color: orange;
}
a[name] {
color: pink;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://google.com">External link</a>
<a name="Mark">Anchor link</a>
```